# how to retrieve url from a html format in R?

Tags: html, r, xpath

in the website "[http://www.amazon.com/Logitech-910-002974-Wireless-Mouse-Scrolling/dp/B007T1CTDE/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1396676617&sr=8-4&keywords=logitech+mouse](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B007T1CTDE)"

I want to retrieve the link

```
"/product-reviews/B002HWRJBC/ref=sp_detail_page_cr_lnk"
```

in

```
<a class="a-size-base" href="/product-reviews/B002HWRJBC/ref=sp_detail_page_cr_lnk">520</a>
```

Can anyone help me with the Xpath?
Thank you!

Comment: There is no such link when I open the webpage (as Amazon pages are highly customized they might deliver different output to different users). So you might want to put the HTML you see in the question. However, you can solve this on your own: Using Firebug (Firefox) or the Chrome Developer Tools you can simply select the element you want and using a right mouse click you can copy the XPath.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to scrape Amazon reviews? I wrote a [package for this](https://github.com/robertzk/amazonreviews) in response to [another StackOverflow question](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3arX9xGQfugw0J%3astackoverflow.com/questions/22595269/opinion-mining-using-r-on-amazon-reviews+&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us).